# How to select a region of interest (ROI) in Google colab (session crashes)?

Tags: python, crash, google-colaboratory

I am trying to execute the following code in Google Colab:

```
#Library load
from skimage import io, util
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

try:
  img = io.imread("database/tiburon.png")

  #Show image
  plt.figure(1)
  plt.imshow(img)

  #Select ROI
  r = cv2.selectROI(img)
except:
  print("Image doesn't exist. Please, select a correct path")
```

However, when I execute it, the session crashes in the command `r = cv2.selectROI(img)` and I haven't found another way to select the ROI of an image. Hence, I'd like to know if there is a solution or an equivalent function to calculate the ROI of an image.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this isn't supported yet in Colab. Would something like this work for you? https://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/box_draw_roi_editor.html